# Anaconda failed building wheel for faulthandler on TravisCI for python 2.7

Tags: python, anaconda, travis-ci, pytest, faulthandler

I'm using TravisCI to [run my unit tests for python 2.7, 3.4, 3.5 and 3.6](https://travis-ci.org/justinsalamon/scaper/builds/280627138). My [.travis.yml](https://github.com/justinsalamon/scaper/blob/master/.travis.yml) file includes the line `- pip install pytest-faulthandler`, which until 2 days ago gave me no issues. Then, yesterday, for no apparent reason, this line started causing the Travis build to [crash](https://travis-ci.org/justinsalamon/scaper/jobs/280627139) with error:

`The command "pip install pytest-faulthandler" failed and exited with 1 during .`

This in turn seems to stem from a bad path to gcc (set by anaconda?):

`unable to execute 'x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc': No such file or directory`

Detailed error log below. As far as I can tell I haven't changed anything to my configuration (`travis.yml`, `setup.cfg`, `setup.py`) that could influence this. The problem only happens for python 2.7, for 3.4-3.6 travis builds the environment without any issues.

I've tried searching online to see if anyone's experienced/solved this issue already, but no luck. Any suggestions/advice would be most welcome. Thanks!

Travis error log below, the complete build log can be found [here](https://travis-ci.org/justinsalamon/scaper/jobs/280627139).

```
Collecting pytest-faulthandler
  Downloading pytest_faulthandler-1.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pytest>=2.6 (from pytest-faulthandler)
  Downloading pytest-3.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (187kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 194kB 4.7MB/s 
Collecting faulthandler; python_version == "2.6" or python_version == "2.7" (from pytest-faulthandler)
  Downloading faulthandler-3.0.tar.gz (55kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 8.7MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /home/travis/miniconda/envs/test-environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pytest>=2.6->pytest-faulthandler)
Collecting py>=1.4.33 (from pytest>=2.6->pytest-faulthandler)
  Using cached py-1.4.34-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: faulthandler
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for faulthandler ... error
  Complete output from command /home/travis/miniconda/envs/test-environment/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-wI1YGd/faulthandler/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpyGVM8Opip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'faulthandler' extension
  creating build
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
  x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O3 -pipe -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/travis/miniconda/envs/test-environment/include/python2.7 -c faulthandler.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/faulthandler.o
  unable to execute 'x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc': No such file or directory
  error: command 'x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for faulthandler
  Running setup.py clean for faulthandler
Failed to build faulthandler
Installing collected packages: py, pytest, faulthandler, pytest-faulthandler
  Running setup.py install for faulthandler ... error
    Complete output from command /home/travis/miniconda/envs/test-environment/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-wI1YGd/faulthandler/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-lKAMMU-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'faulthandler' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O3 -pipe -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/travis/miniconda/envs/test-environment/include/python2.7 -c faulthandler.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/faulthandler.o
    unable to execute 'x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc': No such file or directory
    error: command 'x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/travis/miniconda/envs/test-environment/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-wI1YGd/faulthandler/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-lKAMMU-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-wI1YGd/faulthandler/
The command "pip install pytest-faulthandler" failed and exited with 1 during .
Your build has been stopped.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After additional searching I found [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46450912/unable-to-execute-x86-64-conda-cos6-linux-gnu-gcc-no-such-file-or-directory), following which I replaced the miniconda version in `.travis.yml` to `Miniconda2-4.3.21-Linux-x86_64.sh` for Python 2 and `Miniconda3-4.3.21-Linux-x86_64.sh` for Python 3, and prevented conda from updating by commenting out `- conda update -q conda`. This time [my environment built correctly for all python versions](https://travis-ci.org/justinsalamon/scaper/builds/280943817), problem fixed.

As noted in the linked post, this seems like a bug in the installation script for Anaconda (and miniconda) 4.3.27, and the solution is to use an earlier version (e.g. 4.3.21) and prevent conda from updating.